# Was Jesus an alcoholic?

Tags: life-of-jesus, wine, alcohol

We all know that Jesus could make water into wine but was he an alcoholic?

Comment: +1. There were probably a big number of people at the wedding in Kana. Jesus and his disciples most likely were moderate in their consumption of wine, but there must have been people at the wedding who drank too much and had afterparties at questionable other venues.  I assume that Jesus felt somewhat responsible for these people, and that much of his subsequent final act touched on this problem.

Comment: Suggest getting back under the bridge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a huge difference between 'drinking wine' (your header question) and 'being an alcoholic' (the body of your question).

Since Jesus said :

> But I say unto you, I will not drink **henceforth** of this fruit of the vine, until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father's kingdom.  [Matthew 26:29 KJV],

it may be inferred that he did drink wine (prior to 'henceforth') but it cannot be categorically stated.

However it is quite clear from all the documented evidence of Matthew, Mark, Luke and John that Jesus of Nazareth was not addicted to alcohol nor susceptible, nor vulnerable in that kind of way.

He quite clearly had considerable control over himself, as witnessed by a forty day fast in the wilderness.

Yes, Jesus made water into wine as a sign of something spiritual but providing wine to be drunk (in moderation) at a wedding cannot be seen to be harming others nor can it be seen as reflecting on the susceptibilities of the provider.

Answer (score 2):

In Mtt 11:19, Jesus says: "The Son of Man came eating and drinking; and you call him a glutton and friend of sinners". He was not referring to drinking tea or coffee, but to wine made from grapes. He also said the parable of the vineyard where the owner had made a wine-press ( Mk 12 ) So, Jesus was not against making of wine or drinking it . But there is a difference between using grape wine as an appetizer (1 Tim 5:23) vis- a- vis using it as a 'kick-maker '. And the Lord knew the difference !

Comment: _Glutton and ***wine-bibber_*** was the accusation : Luke 7:34 and Matthew 11:19 (KJV).

Comment: Thanks, Nigel J. You are right. Some versions use the word ' drunkard ' and some, ' heavy drinker '.

Comment: By the way, does Mtt 26:29 refer to wine with alcoholic content, or just to freshly crushed grape-,juice ? Were the Jews permitted to take yeast-made drinks during Passover , when bread of  leavened dough was not permitted ?

Answer (score 1):

**Was Jesus an alcoholic?**

The resounding answer is **no**.

Although there is no historical evidence that Christ was an alcoholic, it seems others may have said it to discredit him.

> 33 For John the Baptist came neither eating bread nor drinking wine, and ye say, ‘He hath a devil.’
>
> 34 The Son of Man is come eating and drinking, and ye say, ‘Behold, a gluttonous man and a winebibber, a friend of publicans and sinners!’
>
> 35 But wisdom is justified by all her children.” - [Luke 7:33-35](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%207&version=KJ21)

Even on the Cross, Jesus refused a concoction that would ease his pain!

> And when they came to a place called Golgotha, which means Place of a Skull, they gave Him wine to drink mixed with gall; and after tasting it, He was unwilling to drink. - Matthew 27:33-34  (NASB)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. If Jesus was an alcoholic (or drunkard), He would have been a practicing sinner. That would have disqualified Him from being our Savior. See, Galatians 5:19-21, Romans 1:4

Answer (score 1):

No where in scripture is it revealed or implied that Jesus was an alcoholic. As a sinless man he had no addictions. Why did he drink wine??? Because 90% of the water in Jerusalem was contaminated. Besides filtering, drinking alcohol was used to clean the water.  Therefore people drank water mixed with a little wine. That hardly qualifies as addiction so NO, Jesus was not an alcoholic.